# XAMPP: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly, have tried re-installing everything still doesnt work

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have installed XAMPP on windows 10, and Apache is running just fine but have an issue running MySQL. This is the error I get on XAMPP window:

```
14:23:51  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
14:23:51  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 

14:23:51  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
14:23:51  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
14:23:51  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
14:23:51  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
14:23:51  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

and this is what I have in the mysql_error.log:

```
2019-09-21 14:21:30 2ca4 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2019-09-21 14:21:30 11428 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool at least up to 20MB.

2019-09-21 14:21:30 11428 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2019-09-21 14:21:30 11428 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2019-09-21 14:21:30 11428 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-09-21 14:21:30 11428 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2019-09-21 14:21:30 11428 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-09-21 14:21:30 11428 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2019-09-21 14:21:30 11428 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2019-09-21 14:21:30 11428 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-09-21 14:21:30 11428 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2019-09-21 14:21:31 11428 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2019-09-21 14:21:31 11428 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-09-21 14:21:31 11428 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.42-84.2 started; log sequence number 1835037
2019-09-21 14:21:31 8100 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2019-09-21 14:21:31 11428 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-09-21 14:21:31 11428 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2019-09-21 14:21:31 11428 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.


2019-09-21 14:21:31 11428 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2019-09-21 14:21:31 11428 [ERROR] Aborting

2019-09-21 14:23:47 2f80 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2019-09-21 14:23:47 12160 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool at least up to 20MB.

2019-09-21 14:23:47 12160 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2019-09-21 14:23:47 12160 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2019-09-21 14:23:47 12160 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-09-21 14:23:47 12160 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2019-09-21 14:23:47 12160 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-09-21 14:23:47 12160 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2019-09-21 14:23:47 12160 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2019-09-21 14:23:47 12160 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-09-21 14:23:47 12160 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2019-09-21 14:23:48 12160 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2019-09-21 14:23:48 12160 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-09-21 14:23:48 12160 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.42-84.2 started; log sequence number 1835047
2019-09-21 14:23:49 5728 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2019-09-21 14:23:49 12160 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-09-21 14:23:49 12160 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2019-09-21 14:23:49 12160 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.


2019-09-21 14:23:49 12160 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2019-09-21 14:23:49 12160 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Have no idea what is going on re-installed the MySQL server this time enabled the InnoDB cluster still same error, someone please help, I am building a website and cant really test anything.. SOS

Answer (score 0):

1. Change port of MySQL in the configuraiton file to 3306
2. Check if there is another service using 10048
3. If 1 and 2 don't work, change your port to one of these list: https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-guide-to-ports/

Comment: i just uninstalled xampp and installed it again and it works, thanks for the asnwe though